# i can't make open/read/close low level functions to work in Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, posix

I am trying to develop a proof-of-concept program that opens a file, reads some data and closes it, all without using the fopen/getc/fclose function. Instead i am using the low level open/read/close equivalents but without luck:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {

    int fp;

    ssize_t num_bytes;

    if ( fp = open ( "test.txt", O_RDONLY ) < 0 ) {
            perror("Error opening file");
            return 1;
    }

    char header[2];

    while ( num_bytes = read ( fp, &header, 2 ) > 0 )
            printf("read %i bytes\n", num_bytes);

    printf("done reading\n");

    close ( fp );

    return 0;
}
```

If no file exists, open correctly prints an error message. If, on the other hand, the file exists, the program stalls at the read() function, for no apparent reason. Any help on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is incorrect due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence):

```
if ( fp = open ( "test.txt", O_RDONLY ) < 0 )
```

as `=` has a lower precedence than `<`. This means that `fp` will be assigned either `0` or `1`, depending on the result of `open ( "test.txt", O_RDONLY ) < 0`.

- When the file does not exist the condition is `-1 < 0`, which the result of is `1` and `fp` is assigned `1` and the `if` branch is entered.
- When the file does exist the condition is `N < 0` (where `N` will be greater than two due `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` occupying file descriptors `0`, `1` and `2`) and `fp` is assigned `0` and the `if` branch is not entered. The program then continues to the `read()` line but `fp` has the value of `0`, which is `stdin` so it stalls as it is waiting to read something from `stdin`.

Change to:

```
if ( (fp = open ( "test.txt", O_RDONLY )) < 0 )
```

Same issue here:

```
while ( num_bytes = read ( fp, &header, 2 ) > 0 )
```

Comment: Obviously i should have checked more closely what gcc reports via the -Wall switch

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
while ( num_bytes = read ( fp, &header, 2 ) > 0 )
```

to

```
while ( (num_bytes = read ( fp, &header, 2 )) > 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

'<' or >'  is having precedence over '='

So the result of comparison which will be either ''0' or '1' will be assigned to fp.

Modify the code like below,

if (    (fp = open ( "test.txt", O_RDONLY ))   < 0    )